# Two Javascript scripts conflicting and causing one not to run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that displays a modal on my page and I recently added Facebook's Messenger script as well. After adding Facebook's script, it works but my modal does not.

Do you see any problem here that would keep the modal script from functioning?

**Facebook Script**

```
    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v8.0'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
    <div class="fb-customerchat" attribution=setup_tool page_id="1803357819897350">
    </div>
```

**Modal Script**

```
    <!-- Modal Javascript -->
    <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#registrationModal').modal();
    }, 4000);
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried stripping down the entire page to just those things?

Comment: I do not see anything in the very limited amount of HTML and JavaScript shown that would cause problems. There is likely other code that may be conflicting.